# PHP / FTP - Simple ftp_get won't work on local server but does in production - Troubleshooting

Tags: php, ftp, centos

I'm having a little problem with ftp_get. The script won't work when running on our local development server running on Centos 6.

I've done some research on Stack Overflow and tried most of the solutions without getting it to work.

I have tested the same script on a production server running Centos 5.x + cPanel and it's working.

I am wondering what could cause this on the local server?

Is there any specific settings for the file transfer to work?

Here's the list of things I've tried so far:

- Errors, `error_reporting(E_ALL)` and see if there's any error. They were none.
- Passive connection, `ftp_pasv($connection, true)` but it doesn't change anything.
- Transfer modes, tried FTP_BINARY and FTP_ASCII. Nothing changes.
- Tried using a file handler to save on the local server, didn't work either.

The original script runs in batch (download all files in a folder with specified filename). When running that script, I can say 3/4 of files get transfered succesfully to the 'dev' server.

Say about only 1/4 of them get the 'failed'. So the following script was used to troubleshoot / test-download some files that failed during the batch transfer.

They also failed transferring using this script.

I've checked all the permissions (chmod) on the distant server. Everything is set to 666.

Here's the code I'm using. It's very similar to the example on php.net

```
// Connection to ftp
$connection = ftp_connect($hostname);

// Login to the FTP
$login = ftp_login($connection, $username, $password);

// Passive might help?
ftp_pasv($connection, true);

// Test login
if ((!$connection) || (!$login)) {
    echo "FTP Connection failed<br /><br />";
    exit;
} else {
    echo "Connection success<br /><br />";
}

$local_file = 'file.zip';
$server_file = 'file.zip';

// Download and save file
if (ftp_get($connection, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_ASCII)){
    echo "Download win <br />";
} else {
    echo "Download failed <br />";
}
```

Thanks for your time,

Comment: Does it work locally if you use a standard client?

Comment: It does, but I wouldn't be downloading it from the actual 'development' server. I would be downloading from my desktop (windows) computer to the local server hard drive, which is network mapped on my desktop.

Comment: I've tested your example using `ftp://ftp.debian.org` as $hostname and it worked. I've tested on CentOS6.3 (php5.3.3) cli. Can you `telnet YOUR_FTP_SERVERS_IP 21` from command line of CentOS?

Comment: Telnet was not installed. I did and tried.
`[root@dev ~]# telnet the-remote-server.com 21
    Trying XX.XX.XXX.XX ...
    Connected to the-remote-server.com`

It did work.

Answer (score 1):

first try checking the same thing from command-line/shell of your local centos machine.  Use "ftp " command and see if it works there.  Mostly, it seems like a firewall problem to me.

Comment: I should have mention that when running the script in 'batch' it would download some files and fail on others. I've tested the files that would fail (access wise) and they are exisiting, pointing to the correct path and not corrupted. So it's working, but part time. The test I've posted is for one of the file that wouldn't download. There is something I should also say: I know there no ftp service installed on this dev server. We use the sFTP2 protocol for 'wordpress updates' and such. Does FTP service need to be installed to be able to download files from PHP FTP function?

Comment: No its hasn't to be installed. Do you know tcpdump? You'll have to see whats going over the wire. As ftp is a text oriented protocol its easy to debug-

Comment: No, it shouldn't need the service running.  Check out: http://php.net/manual/en/ftp.installation.php ; What I understood from ur comment is, there is a file that doesn't download even in batch/command-line mode.  Is that the only file not downloaded despite proper access rights etc?

Comment: @T.Vyas Sorry if it was not clear. The original script runs in batch (download all files in a folder with specified filename). When running that script, I can say 3/4 of files get transfered succesfully to the 'dev' server. Only 1/4 of them get the 'failed'. So I've builded a standalone script to troubleshoot / test-download some files that failed during the batch transfer. I've checked all the permissions (chmod) on the distant server. Everything is set to 666.

Comment: @hek2mgl I don't know tcpdump, but since some files will transfer and some won't, I'm not sure the problem would be 'that' deep. Am I wrong?

Comment: @aurevilly, if some 1/4th of files are not downloading, it means there is something wrong with those files(not just permissions).  Is there anything unique/different about the failing files? e.g. different dir. etc?  Also try using ftp -d switch for debugging individual failing file.. that might reveal some more info..

Comment: @aurevilly I would expect it that deep although I would not say analysing network traffic and search for errors is 'that' deep ;) Also you should have look at the logfiles of the ftp server.